# Spring boot ignores/not working with custom MySqlDialect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

This is my custom dialect

```
public class MyOwnSQLDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {

    public MyOwnSQLDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerFunction("group_concat", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.STRING, "group_concat(?1)"));
    }
}
```

here is my property to use it

**application.properties**

`**spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=demo.orm.config.MyOwnSQLDialect**`

I'm using Spring boot with spring JPA data.

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@ComponentScan(value = {"demo.eaze.*"})
//@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableWebFlux
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context
                     = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                Application.class)) {

            context.getBean(NettyContext.class).onClose().block();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public NettyContext nettyContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        HttpHandler handler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder
                .applicationContext(context).build();
        ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter
                = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(handler);
        HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create("localhost", 8080);
        return httpServer.newHandler(adapter).block();
    }
}
```

Another file is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfigs {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        System.out.println("ApplicationConfigs.init");
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Above code works if I use  JPA/Hibernate but when I'm using this with Spring boot project, it's not working.

My main idea to add custom Dialect is due to using some SQL functions like 
`GROUP_CONCAT` in JPA Criteria builder API

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0")
    //compile("com.h2database:h2")
//    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jjwt:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11'

    //  providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
}
```

Comment: Always a good idea to swear at the people that you want help from. Didn't downvote, but there nothing in your question indicating why you came to the conclusion that your configuration gets ignored. And finally, you seem to use a spring boot configuration but don't seem to use Spring Boot.

Comment: @JensSchauder :) Dear, Rather posting whole Gradle dependency file and extra stuff, I tried to ask specific.  The conclusion is on behalf if U'll comment the line means if u'll not provide the property of dialect, spring boot autoconfiguration automatically apply the mysql dialect, 
 
I want to declare my custom dialect, this is because I want some custom functions in my crieteria API.

Comment: @JensSchauder If u'll read my question and code, u'll come to know i'm using spring-boot with webFlux.

Comment: Here's how you start a Spring boot app: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-code. Note that you're not supposed to create an AnnotationConfigApplicationContext by yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks buddy, But it's my working ongoing project. My concern is not how to create or start spring boot. My question is little tricky. Please read the question, I want to add my custom dialect, it's not a regular dialect here. I want to achieve extra functionality which is possible by registering our new custom Dialect.

The same works with JPA standalone project if I provide custom MySql dialect.

Comment: Given that the application properties are handled by Spring Boot, and that you're not starting your app as documented by the Spring Boot documentation, I'm not surprised you don't get Spring-Boot functionalities.

Comment: @JBNizet I agreed with u if my db credentials and other stuffs were not working. but they are working. 
But still I'll take a look in the documentation. 

Meanwhile, if we can talk specific, do u have any idea how we can add custom mysql dialect in spring-boot project. Please suggest me if have any idea.

Comment: @JBNizet Please note that, it's a WebFlux based configuration rather traditional spring-boot

Comment: So you aren't using Spring Boot and expect that Spring Boot features will work... Use the `SpringApplication` class to bootstrap your application not the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Dear, If I'll use webflux, I've to change SpringBootApplication to NettyContext. It's a spring boot reactive webflux. I don't know why all are forcing to prove that project is of spring boot  or not, rather I want a solution which can provide CuStom Dialect working either with spring boot with webflux functionality.

Comment: Spring Boot automatically will start Netty for you. The problem you are facing is you probably read 2 tutorials one using and one not using Spring Boot and try to make both work. As stated it won't, you cannot use spring boot features without spring boot. Simply let spring boot start your application, remove the Netty bean as Spring Boot will start that for you as well, just include the `spring-boot-starter-webflux`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I started via spring site, please see my Gradle dependencies. webflux is already there. my project working accordingly. My question is different, I don't understand why My question is misleading.

Comment: Your question clearly states that you are using spring boot, but you aren't (apart from the dependency management).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you configure your dialect using a mechanism of Spring Boot. 
But your application (the one started by your `main` method is not a Spring Boot Application, therefore, none of the Spring Boot mechanisms actually happens.

In order to fix this make your application a proper Spring Boot Application or use standard Hibernate way to configure your dialect.

For the Spring Boot way of things see this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

For setting the SqlDialect in Hibernate see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects